# Поменять версию в JitPack?

Tags: java, android, github, gradle

Я закинул свою библиотеку на GitHub и подключал ее с помощью JitPack. Текущая версия 1.0. Как можно поменять версию на 1.1? Я изменил версию в buiild.gradle, но это не помогло. Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания новой версии нужно сделать релиз библиотеки на GitHub.

Источник: https://jitpack.io/docs/#publishing-on-jitpack